# How can i change layout when orientation is change

Tags: layout, blackberry

I want to change my blackberry screen GUI When i go from portrait to landscape mode.

```
protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(Display.getOrientation()==Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        label.setText("Portrait");
    }
    else
    {
        label.setText("Landscape");
    }

    super.sublayout(width, height);
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override [sublayout](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/FullScreen.html#sublayout%28int,%20int%29) on your screen, this is called whenever the orientation changes so you can use it to add/remove/change fields.

You can also use Display.getOrientation() to check the current orientation. You should also track the previous orientation within your application in case sublayout was called for a different reason.

Comment: I already did this thing see code update..But it gives illegalstateexception

Comment: Try synchronize on the event thread before you set the text. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiHZrkNIbXA&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it manually.  Whenever orientation changes in blackberry it calls the subLayout() method. There you can call invalidate method which will refresh your screen. But make sure that you are using relative layout instead of absolute layouts. It will automatically arrange the UI elements in your screen.

Comment: I'm not familiar with setLayout in BB isn't that Android?